# Help me with this rebus puzzle

Tags: riddle, rebus

I don't know what this is. Can anyone help me? It's for a raffle at work. I got the "I Think" part but I am stuck on the rest. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Comment: Answered, yet no check mark. We'll probably never see Kartinos again. Bloody tourists!

Answer (score 10):

Here's my guess

> I think positive wonderful thoughts

Explanation

> The eye and ink are straightforward. W under Full. And another word for 0 is naught. So together, that sounds like thoughts.

Comment: WOW! I think you are right!! that is awesome :) thank you so much!

Comment: Better yet, another word for zero is rot13(nhtug).

Comment: I would use "sum" (some) instead of "positive".

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain yeah, that sounds plausible too.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain - I think that makes sense! thank you to all who helped

Comment: @KartinosLSlim Make sure to click the green checkmark if it's a good answer.